# How to structure Python script to make settings available to all functions?

Tags: python, configuration-files

I'm working on a simple CLI script that's not unlike this toy example,

1. Helper Function, `test(dict)` - run tests on `dict` using settings from CSV config file.
2. Function, `OpenFile(file)` - opens file and returns `dict` result. Calls `test()`
3. Function, `GetFiles(dir)` - takes a directory and runs `OpenFile()`

Execution is naturally like this: Call #3, then #2 & #1 run for as many files in directory.

I'm sure it's not a best practice to load CSV config file for each call. It only needs to be loaded once.

What's the simplest and most direct way to load configuration settings and make them available to all functions where they are required? Also, using only the standard library.

---

PS.
I'm feeling like a total NOOB on this one, but every idea I have just seems too complicated. I'm really just looking for an idiom which I can use when I mock up my idea, before practical requirements necessitate the need for full-function solutions such as `config` module.

Comment: show us the representative contents of your script and how you intend to call if from the command line

Comment: It's 500 lines scraping a PDF file into Pandas DataFrames. Uses concat to join all the DFs into one, adds a header file, and saves the result as CSV. The `test()` performs a calculation on each dataframe to ensure success. It's called using Click module, as in `$ GetFiles dir` in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example (unless the CSV file is huge) it won't make a difference in performance.

However it isn't best practice to load the CSV every time, so use the `import config` module option. it's actually quite versitile

There is a good article on it here :) 
https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-manage-the-configuration-in-python-4623049e841b

Comment: I added at the last minute the suggestion to do it without additional modules. Any ideas without another module dependency? Should I make Global variables?

Comment: it's not an additional module. most of the time a literally write a `config.py` file and import it.

Comment: `configparser` is also part of the python standard library https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html?highlight=config#module-configparser